# Who killed Ariana Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, gellert-grindelwald

Is there any part in the 7th book where it is detailed of who personally killed Ariana Dumbledore from the trio's duel?

> “And there was an argument . . . and I pulled out my wand, and he
>   pulled out his, and I had the Cruciatus Curse used on me by my
>   brother’s best friend — and Albus was trying to stop him, and then
>
> all three of us were dueling, and the flashing lights and the bangs
>   set her off, she couldn’t stand it —” The color was draining from
>   Aberforth’s face as though he had suffered a mortal wound. “— and I
>   think she wanted to help, but she didn’t really know what she was
>   doing, and I don’t know which of us did it, it could have been any of
>   us — and she was dead.”

```
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Chapter 28 Missing Mirror
```

I don't quite remember if it was mentioned in the books.

Answer (score 5):

## Don't know.

> “— and I think she wanted to help, but she didn’t really know what she was doing, and **I don’t know which of us did it**, it could have been any of us — and she was dead.”

It never says in the seven books or TCC who actually killed her. It could have been Grindelwald, Albus, or Aberforth.

I would guess GG, since he's probably the only one who would cast something fatal, as he had just demonstrated his willingness to use the Unforgivable Curses.

Comment: yes. I also guess it could be Gellert. after all, he's a dark wizard. Or maybe a certain spell had been reflected to her

Comment: The cause of death is similarly unknown, it's not necessarily AK

Comment: @Caleth edited.